# Programmatically adding form action attributes in Pug/Jade within while loops

Tags: node.js, forms, express, pug

I have the following code for adding server-side data to the client using pug, Express, and Node:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        .container
            h3= data[i].id
            h5= data[i].Message
            form(action="#data[i].upvoteFormAction", method="POST")
                button.btn.btn-success(type="submit")
                    h7 Upvote
                h7= data[i].Upvotes                 
            br
            form(action=data[i].downvoteFormAction, method="POST")
                button.btn.btn-danger(type="submit")
                    h7 Downvote
                h7= data[i].Downvotes

-}
```

Everything is rendering perfectly like I expect, but the form action associated with this Express route does not behave as desired:

```
router.post('/upvote/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send(200);
});
```

Instead of getting the http 200 status code as expected when I click on the programmatically rendered form for the upvote buttons, I get:

```
Cannot POST /
```

and this is the URL in my browser:

http://localhost:3000/#data[i].upvoteFormAction

suggested that quotes should not be there.

When I remove the quotes, I get "Unexpected character" for a rendering error in Pug, and the same applies to different permutations of # and { with and without escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pug supports any JavaScript value for attributes, but doesn't support this `#` prefixed syntax.  You can just write:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        .container
            h3= data[i].id
            h5= data[i].Message
            form(action=data[i].upvoteFormAction, method="POST")
                button.btn.btn-success(type="submit")
                    h7 Upvote
                h7= data[i].Upvotes                 
            br
            form(action=data[i].downvoteFormAction, method="POST")
                button.btn.btn-danger(type="submit")
                    h7 Downvote
                h7= data[i].Downvotes

-}
```

It looks like you were already doing this correctly in your "Downvote" button.

You can also simplify your code by using pug's built in `each` syntax:

```
each item in data
    .container
        h3= item.id
        h5= item.Message
        form(action=item.upvoteFormAction, method="POST")
            button.btn.btn-success(type="submit")
                h7 Upvote
            h7= item.Upvotes                 
        br
        form(action=item.downvoteFormAction, method="POST")
            button.btn.btn-danger(type="submit")
                h7 Downvote
            h7= item.Downvotes
```